# how to localize object with CNN?

Tags: python, object-detection, conv-neural-network

```
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding = 'same' ,activation = 'relu', input_shape= (image_width,image_height,image_channels)),
keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'),
keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding = "same",activation = 'relu'),
keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
keras.layers.Flatten(),
keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = 'relu'),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
keras.layers.Dense(5,activation = 'softmax')
])
```

This is my model that have been trained and get above 85% of accuracy for classifying 5 classess of flower. For the classification it works well and successfully classify most of the images. But for the object localization what layers should I add up in order to localize and detect the flower object within the test images?

Comment: I recommend reading some articles about object localization. Do you want a per-pixel localization ("segmentation", one predictor per pixel) or a rectangular bounding box ("object detection", four predictors: center-x, center-y, width, height)? It really requires some thought and is not just a matter of "adding some layer", even though you could just throw in another `Dense(4)` and train it to find the bounding box parameters.

Comment: Yes I have read through some articles but all the things I could find is theoretical stuff, so for the practical I don’t know what to add or that kinda stuff. Could u tell more about adding dense(4)? Thanks in advance

Comment: I really recommend understanding some of that theoretical stuff or using pretrained models for these tasks ("transfer learning"). But what you could do if you don't want to change your model too much is to feed your last dropout layer in your classification `Dense(5, softmax)` layer alternating with a localization `Dense(4, relu)` layer. So for each iteration you either apply classification or localization loss and do the backpropagation for the respective loss, so that your network learns both tasks. You now have too tasks: classify and locate, so you have two losses.